# In Selenium 1, why are all the browser commands prefixed with an asterix?

Tags: selenium

Running Selenium 1 locally (not through grid) all the supported browser strings are prefixed by *. Assuming Selenium-Server has already been started

```
return new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox", "http://www.google.com");
```

Is this just a convention, or does it have some functional purpose? Note that we executing with an unsupported browser type is a nice way to get a list of the supported browsers.

```
return new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "firefox", "http://www.google.com");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add an asterisk in front of the browser name, you are telling selenium to treat it as a "special browser setting", which will allow selenium to automatically configure it if needed (for example disable pop-up blocking). It is recommended to use this option. For further details see [here](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/SRC/Specifications+for+Selenium+Remote+Control+Client+Driver+Protocol#SpecificationsforSeleniumRemoteControlClientDriverProtocol-5.3.3getNewBrowserSession%28%29%28RECOMMENDED%29) and [here](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/SRC/Specifications+for+Selenium+Remote+Control+Client+Driver+Protocol#SpecificationsforSeleniumRemoteControlClientDriverProtocol-5.3.3.1SupportedSpecialBrowserStrings%28RECOMMENDED%29) in selenium documentation.

from the same links:

> "browserString" MUST be either an absolute file path to a browser
>   executable, or a special string starting with an asterisk '*'. (See
>   the next section for details.)

and

> Supporting the following special browserStrings is RECOMMENDED:
>
> *firefox
>   *iexplore
>   *opera
>   *netscape
>   *konqueror
>   *safari
>   *seamonkey
>   *omniweb
>   *camino The Server MAY support other special browserStrings.
>
> If the Client Driver issues a "getNewBrowserSession" Command Request
>   for one of these strings, the Server SHOULD launch the specified
>   browser.
>
> When the Server launches the browser using a special browserString,
>   the Server MAY automatically configure the browser in a way that makes
>   it suitable for automated testing. For example the Server MAY disable
>   pop-up blocking or unnecessary security prompts.
>
> The Server MAY allow options to be specified in the browserString, by
>   appending them to one of the supported browserStrings. For example,
>   the Server MAY allow the Client Driver to specify an absolute path to
>   Firefox while the Server automatically configures it by accepting the
>   browserString "*firefox c:\firefox\firefox.exe".